# Error controller not being hit due to Fallback controller

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm running a .NET Core 3.1 Web API project and below is my pipeline. The problem I face is that when an error occurs, I want the error controller to be hit and the error to be logged. However, what is returned is the html from the fallback controller. Can you help me fix this routing issue?

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "KYCDB API"));

app.UseRouting();            
app.UseCors(); 
    
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
});

app.UseHealthChecks("/api/monitor");
```

this is my error controller

```
[ApiController]
    public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> logger;

        public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger) => this.logger = logger;

        [Route("/error")]
        [NonAction]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            logger.LogError(exception.Error.Message, exception); 
            return Problem(detail: exception.Error.Message);
        }
    }
```

and the fallback controller

```
public class FallbackController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index() => PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "index.html"), "text/HTML");
    }
```

Comment: `The problem I face is that when an error occurs, I want the error controller to be hit and the error to be logged. However, what is returned is the html from the fallback controller.` Which type of the error? 404 error or 500 error? Please clarify more about the issue, so that we can understand and help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: The unhandled 500 errors are the ones that i'm after to log. I actually made this work by playing with the attributes the ErrorController. After I removed the NonAction attribute, then it started functioning like a normal controller. The downside is that now it also appears on the Swagger documentation, which isn't ideal.